# Is it possible to set up the Mailman rest interface in Mailman3 over ssl?

Tags: mailman

The documentation says that the Mailman rest interface provides http basic authentication.  Is it possible to configure the rest API to accept (only?) SSL connections?  The documentation, for example, https://docs.mailman3.org/en/latest/prodsetup.html says that the REST interface should never be exposed on the public internet but the Mailman service may be in a different host that other processes using the REST api, so securing the Basic AUTH is still desirable.